# Free alternative for Shopify and Magento

Tags: online-payment

I'm looking for a good alternative for [Shopify](http://www.shopify.com/) or [Magento](http://magento.com/), but preferably low-cost or free. Here are the minimum features I need:

- Free/low-cost hosting (or easy setup)
- Shipping integration
- Mt. Gox or Bitpay integration (optional)

Comment: Doesn't this mean “any e-commerce platform, and I don't want to pay (much)”? This question is far too broad. A good software recommendation question should define reasonably specific requirements (yours are too broad) and a purpose (e.g. “I want to run a site with about P products, about C customers, a turnover of X, these payment methods, integration with this backend database, …”). Please read our [question quality guidelines](meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336) and our [tips on asking for alternatives](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48) (why not Shopify or Magento?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Opencart](http://www.opencart.com)  is a free open source alternative.

- You can install extensions like [Bitpay](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=3119)
- It's easy to install
- Includes 10 shipping methods ([See here](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=feature/feature&path=9))
- Written in PHP